# Calculate $\int_C \vec G \cdot d\vec r$ for $\vec G = 3y\vec i -3x\vec j$ along a simple closed curve

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors

$C_1$ and $C_2$ start at $(-1,1)$ and end at $(1,-1)$. $C = C_2 - C_1$.

[image]

So I believe the radius of the semicircle is $1$, its circumference is $2\pi / 2 = \pi$, and its area is $\pi / 2$. If I'm wrong about any of that, then that will explain my confusion.

But assuming that's all right, I want to calculate the following:

$$\int_{C} \vec G \cdot d\vec r $$

I think I can use Green's Theorem: curl $\vec G = -6$, and the area of the semicircle is $\pi / 2$, so the $\int_{C_1} \vec G \cdot d\vec r$ should evaluate to $-3\pi$, right? Yet my textbook says the answer is $-6\pi$. Can you see why?

Just to be absolutely sure I'm not misinterpreting the question, I've pasted it in here so you can confirm for yourself:

[image]

Comment: Check the radius of the semicircle again.

Comment: @saulspatz So the semicircle is centered at the origin, so I can calculate the distance from the origin to a point on the edge of the semicircle to calculate the radius. The point $(1,-1)$ is on the semicircle, and the distance of that point from the origin is $\sqrt{1^2 + (-1)^2} = 1$, no? OH WOW NEVERMIND, I REALIZED IT JUST BY WRITING IT OUT JUST NOW. THANK YOU!